# Printing output in one line from standard input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read line from standard input, like a string separated by commas, then print it the same line with additional word in one line. However, when printing it out, additional word always prints out in new line. But I need them in one line.

Here is my code

```
while 1:
try:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break

if not line:
    break

additional = "END"
print(line+additional)
```

And when I try it:

```
>>python3.4 output.py
>>a, b
>>a, b
>>END
>>
```

But I want it:

```
>>python3.4 output.py
>>a, b
>>a, bEND
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `line` value *contains a newline character*; strip it from the value:

```
print(line.rstrip('\n') + additional)
```

`str.rstrip()` removes characters from the end; here we ask it to remove all newlines from the end of `line`; it returns the a string object with those newline characters removed.

Demo:

```
>>> line = 'Hello, world!\n'
>>> line.rstrip('\n')
'Hello, world!'
>>> additional = 'END'
>>> print(line + additional)
Hello, world!
END
>>> print(line.rstrip('\n') + additional)
Hello, world!END
```

Comment: thank you very much! I had a gut feeling of 'extra new line character'.